# ClosedXml doesn't copy spreadsheet's printer settings

Tags: c#, excel, printing, closedxml

I have xltx Excel's template, when I create (manually) new document from it and click `File`->`Print` in Excel first sheet fits on one page.

Than I create new document from my template with the help of `ClosedXml`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ClosedXML.Excel;

namespace ClosedXml1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tXltx = "t.xltx";
            using (XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(tXltx))
            {
                using (XLWorkbook newWb = new XLWorkbook())
                {
                    foreach (XLWorksheet worksheet in workbook.Worksheets.Reverse())
                    {
                        worksheet.CopyTo(newWb, worksheet.Name, 1);
                    }

                    newWb.SaveAs("new.xlsx");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I open resulting document and open printing dialog (`File`->`Print`) first sheet doesn't fit on one page.

***UPDATE1:*** `XLWorksheet::CopyTo` copies page setup from original template to resulting workbook. So, if xltx template has page setup `FitToPages(1,1)`, resulting document will have the same page setup. Despite that, when I open printing preview of ClosedXml-generated sheet it doesn't fit one page. ***So, it is problem: original and resulting workbooks have the same page setup, but generated worksheet doesn't fit one page.***

---

**So there are questions**:

- What has to be copied from original template that resulting sheet
  fits one page?
- Is there any way to accomplish it?

---

***Workaround***

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
Workbook original = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(originalFilename);
original.SaveAs(resultingFilename);                    
excelApp.Quit();
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);
```

Comment: Seems like a problem of particular template.

Answer (score 4):

You can check / set the options for this with

```
worksheet.PageSetup.PagesTall
worksheet.PageSetup.PagesWide
worksheet.PageSetup.FitToPages(1, 1)
```

(See the [Documentation](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Pages-Tab).)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ClosedXml will loose these settings when performing **CopyTo**. A particular case is when PagesTall is set to **empty**, it must explicitly set to **-1** on worksheet copy, otherwise ClosedXml will put it to **1**.